# In Sails.js v0.10 after populating data as a value i get [Getter/Setter]

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

After populating data i get result not as expected.

Example:

```
//User.js Model
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    //"id" attribute is here primary key by default

    schools: { collection: 'School', via: 'id' },
    name: { type: 'String', trim: true, required: true }
  }
}
```

And this is my School.js

```
//School.js Model
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    //"id" attribute is here primary key by default

    name: { type: 'String', trim: true, required: true },
  }
}
```

My User entity data looks like this:

```
//User document in MongoDB
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Foo",
  schools: [1,2,3]
}
```

My School entity data looks like this:

```
//School documents in MongoDB
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "School 1"
}
{
    _id: 2,
    name: "School 2"
}
{
    _id: 3,
    name: "School 3"
}
```

Now i want to populate the schools. I do it like this:

```
User.find().populate("schools").exec(function(err, res){ console.log(res[0]) });
```

And this is what i get as a result:

```
{
  schools: [Getter/Setter],
  name: "Foo",
  id: 1
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  schools: [
    {id: 1, name: "School 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "School 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "School 3"}
  ],
  name: "Foo",
  id: 1
}
```

How can i get expected results?

I use MongoDB as data storage.

Versions:

Sails.js: v0.10.0-rc5

Waterline: v0.10.0-rc7

sails-mongo: 0.10.0-rc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the expected results when using `console.log`!  If you want to see the expanded object, do:

```
console.log(res[0].toObject());
```

Comment: Nice. Now i see strange empty array but not expected rows. Do i something wrong?

Comment: Actually, judging from the `User` document you posted, something is missing from your explanation.  The `id` in Mongo should be an ObjectID, not a number, and it shouldn't have a `schools` field at all (there should be a `school_id__user_schools` collection instead).  When I create an app and use the model definitions you provided, it works fine.

Comment: School `_id` is an integer not an ObjectID like `User` has it. I've updated my question (Added School documents). I also see that my `school_id__user_schools` collection is empty. Do i understand it right, I cannot use Integer value in `_id` to get population work?

Comment: Are you using a pre-existing Mongo DB with a new Sails project?  This is fine, but you'll want to set `autoPk: false` on the `School` model, and explicitly define an `id` attribute with an `integer` type.  Then it should work fine, but the embedded `schools` document in the `user` collection in your existing MongoDB is meaningless to Sails (and possibly problematic).  Sails associations work via join tables (in this case `school_id__user_schools`) even for Mongo.  The join table is populated when you add a `School` to a `User` instance via `myUserInstance.schools.add(schoolId)`.